# Tap gesture on UIImageView inside a cell doesn't fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

This is myCell init method

```
- (id)init {

     [...]

     _rightImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 70)];

    [_rightImg setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [
         [UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
         initWithTarget:self 
         action:@selector(handleRightImageTap)];

    [_rightImg addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

    tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

    [self.contentView addSubview:_rightImg];
}
```

And this is my handler method defined in myCell

```
- (void) handleRightImageTap {
     printf("TTTTAAAAPPPPP\n");
}
```

It doesn't work and I don't know what I am doing wrong. Help !

Comment: UIImageView has `userInteraction = NO` by default. Make sure you set it to `YES`

Comment: Have u check userinteraction = true or not?

Comment: [_rightImg setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; ?

Comment: did you do any thing in tapGestureRecognizer delegate ?

Comment: No I didnt' modify tapGestureRecognizer delegate

Comment: try imageview of your cell to bring in front.

Comment: set `numberOfTapRequired=1` and `numberOfTouchesRequired=1`

Answer (score 1):

Write these lines and test , i think the imageView is covered by some other view

```
[self.contentView bringSubviewToFront:_rightImg];
[_rightImg setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Are you able to select the cell, What is mean to say is, Is the `didSelectRowMethod` Called ??

Answer (score 0):

Do the Same stuff in

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
//Do Same Code
}
```

Comment: Where ? what does it do ?

Comment: Its just a NitPicking,If you are working with a UITableViewCell class then you should use "awakeFromNib" instead of "init".

Answer (score 0):

Your `UITapGestureRecognizer` code works no pro. But what's your "init" method?

If load custmosize uitableViewCell from storyboard, you should use `awakeFromNib` or any init method like "`- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`" from code, try it.